File .xlsx creado con ClosedXML marca Error "Archivo dañado" al descargar desde app
Estoy desarrollando en dot.NET, C#. Tengo un archivo de excel con un formato preestablecido y estoy usando ClosedXML para crearlo, uso MemoryStreamy para regresar un arreglo en bits y lo devuelvo al front pueda descargarlo,pero al abrir el archivo .xlsx marca error,indica que el archivo esta dañado.
hola el codigo que uso es el siguiente:
////uso Mediator para la parte del controllador

 [HttpGet("AttendanceByRange/{start:datetime}/{end:datetime}")]
 public async Task<ActionResult> GetAttendanceByRangeAsync(DateTime start, DateTime end, Guid? employeeId)
 {
     var document = await Mediator.Send(new GetAttendanceQuery { StartDate = start, EndDate = end, EmployeeId = employeeId });
     return File(document, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Reporte de Asistencia Rangos.xlsx");
 }

    ////Servicio
    
       public byte[] GetAttendanceReport(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, List<EmployeeAttendanceDTO> attendances)
     {
         using var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
         var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Asistencias");
    
         worksheet.Style.Font.FontName = "Arial";
         worksheet.Style.Font.FontSize = 10;
    
         var difDays = (endDate.Date - startDate.Date).Days + 1;
         var row = 1;
    
         foreach (var employee in attendances)
         {
             worksheet.Range($"A{row}:B{row}").Merge();
             worksheet.Cell($"A{row}").Value = "No. Empleado";
             worksheet.Range($"C{row}").Value = employee.Number;
    
             worksheet.Range($"E{row}:F{row}").Merge();
             worksheet.Cell($"E{row}").Value = "Nombre de empleado";
    
             worksheet.Range($"G{row}:J{row}").Merge();
             worksheet.Range($"G{row}").Value = employee.Name;
    
             worksheet.Range($"L{row}:M{row}").Merge();
             worksheet.Cell($"L{row}").Value = "Department";
    
             worksheet.Range($"N{row}:P{row}").Merge();
             worksheet.Range($"N{row}").Value = employee.Department;
    
             worksheet.Cell($"A{row + 1}").Value = "fecha";
             worksheet.Cell($"A{row + 1}").Style.Font.Bold = true;
    
             var nextRowCheckIn = row + 2;
             var nextRowCheckOut = row + 3;
             var lastRowCheckOut = nextRowCheckOut;
             var employeeAttendanceDate = employee.AttendanceRecords.GroupBy(t => t.Date.Date);
             var checktotal = employeeAttendanceDate.MaxBy(t => t.Count()).Count();
    
             for (int i = 0; i < checktotal; i++)
             {
                 worksheet.Cell($"A{nextRowCheckIn}").Value = "check in";
                 worksheet.Cell($"A{nextRowCheckIn}").Style.Font.Bold = true;
                 worksheet.Cell($"A{nextRowCheckOut}").Value = "check out";
                 worksheet.Cell($"A{nextRowCheckOut}").Style.Font.Bold = true;
    
                 nextRowCheckIn = nextRowCheckOut + 1;
                 nextRowCheckOut = nextRowCheckOut + 2;
             }
    
             lastRowCheckOut = nextRowCheckOut;
             var col = 2;
             for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
             {
    
                 worksheet.Cell(row + 1, col).Value = date.Date.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
                 worksheet.Cell(row + 1, col).Style.Font.FontSize = 7;
    
                 var employeeAttendance = employeeAttendanceDate.Where(t => t.Key.Date.Equals(date.Date))
                     .FirstOrDefault()?.Select(t => new AttendanceRecordDTO
                     {
                         Date = t.Date,
                         CheckIn = t.CheckIn,
                         CheckOut = t.CheckOut
                     })?.ToList()?.OrderBy(o => o.CheckIn);
    
    
                 nextRowCheckIn = row + 2;
                 nextRowCheckOut = row + 3;
    
                 for (int i = 0; i < checktotal; i++)
                 {
                     worksheet.Cell(nextRowCheckIn, col).Style.Font.FontSize = 7;
                     worksheet.Cell(nextRowCheckOut, col).Style.Font.FontSize = 7;
    
                     if (employeeAttendance != null && i < employeeAttendance.Count())
                     {
                         worksheet.Cell(nextRowCheckIn, col).Value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeAttendance?.ElementAt(i).CheckIn) ? employeeAttendance?.ElementAt(i).CheckIn : "-";
                         worksheet.Cell(nextRowCheckOut, col).Value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeAttendance?.ElementAt(i).CheckOut) ? employeeAttendance?.ElementAt(i).CheckOut : "-";
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         worksheet.Cell(nextRowCheckIn, col).Value = "-";
                         worksheet.Cell(nextRowCheckOut, col).Value = "-";
                     }
    
                     nextRowCheckIn = nextRowCheckOut + 1;
                     nextRowCheckOut = nextRowCheckOut + 2;
                 }
    
                 col++;
             }
             row = lastRowCheckOut;
         }
    
         for (var col = 2; col <= difDays; col++)
         {
             worksheet.Column(col).AdjustToContents();
         }
    
         using var ms = new MemoryStream();
         workbook.SaveAs(ms);
         ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
         ms.Flush();
         ms.Position = 0;
    
         return ms.ToArray();
     }

Funciona perfectamente cuando lo pruebo en mi local, pero al pasarlo al hosting me arroja error, anexo imagenes.


agradezco sus comentarios!
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][3]][3]
Usamos el AWS lambda function, pongo una imagen de prueba donde de ambos descarga el archivo el local abre (img Izquierda) pero el de AWS marca error (img Derecha).
[3]: https://i.sstatic.net/LR5L5xhd.png

Edita la pregunta, agrega un código de ejemplo mínimo verificable, y del mismo modo, coloca todo lo que tenga que ver con la puesta en producción (configuración del server).

Gracias @fredyfx  añadí código para poder representar mejor la idea.

Bien, vamos bien, ahora la pregunta es ¿Qué hosting tienes? ¿qué características tiene?

es AWS , pongo una imagen de prueba donde de ambos descarga el archivo el local abre pero el de AWS marca error.

AWS, ok, ¿instancia de docker? ¿Windows server? ¿Alguna distro Linuxera? ¿Nginx? ¿Apache? Edita la pregunta y agrega todos los datos que sean importantes para que cualquier usuario pueda reproducir tu escenario. Con esto, las chances de obtener respuesta aumentan. Saludos :D
